# What does this error message in R mean? And how do I resolve it? Thanks. Error in match(which.row, 1:dim(xy)[2])

Tags: r

I am trying to use an example from the R package "aplpack" for drawing faces and am getting an error message:

Code:

```
xy = matrix(c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,45,567,34,87,98,45,56,23), nrow=5, ncol=3)

faces( xy, which.row, fill = FALSE, face.type = 1, nrow.plot, ncol.plot, 
  scale = TRUE, byrow = FALSE, main, labels, print.info = TRUE, 
  na.rm = FALSE, ncolors = 20, col.nose = rainbow(ncolors), 
  col.eyes = rainbow(ncolors, start = 0.6, end = 0.85), 
  col.hair = terrain.colors(ncolors), col.face = heat.colors(ncolors), 
  col.lips = rainbow(ncolors, start = 0, end = 0.2), 
  col.ears = rainbow(ncolors, start = 0, end = 0.2), plot.faces = TRUE)
```

Output:
    Error in match(which.row, 1:dim(xy)[2]) : object 'which.row' not found

Thank you

Comment: I think you have to specify the arguments i..e. `which.row= 1:3` etc.  If we do `faces(xy)` it works.  Some of the arguments are not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If we specify the arguments correctly, it will work

```
ncolr=20
faces( xy, which.row=1:4, fill = FALSE, face.type = 1, 
  nrow.plot=3, ncol.plot=2,
  scale = TRUE, byrow = FALSE, main='faces', print.info = TRUE, 
   na.rm = FALSE, ncolors = ncolr, col.nose = rainbow(ncolr), 
   col.eyes = rainbow(ncolr, start = 0.6, end = 0.85), 
   col.hair = terrain.colors(ncolr), col.face = heat.colors(ncolr), 
   col.lips = rainbow(ncolr, start = 0, end = 0.2), 
   col.ears = rainbow(ncolr, start = 0, end = 0.2), plot.faces = TRUE)
```

[image]